# How to change rules for byteman at runtime

Tags: java, jboss, bytecode, instrumentation, byteman

I have running remoted test server where I want to make some modifications with existing code using byteman.

Is it possible to attach byteman at runtime with custom rules files (While starting we should set rule file, that is not flexible for most cases)?

Is it possible to attach it to running server without adding -javaagent while starting the server?

Answer (score 0):

there is a very detail tutorial, the URL is : https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ABytemanTutorial#how_do_i_install_the_agent_into_a_running_program

As the tutorial mentioned, you can use **bminstall.sh** to install byteman agent to the running JVM at anytime, after you install byteman agent, you can use **bmsubmit.sh** to submit a byteman script to the JVM.

For example:

**Step 1:**

```
bminstall.sh -h 192.168.0.1 -p 8080 -b -Dorg.jboss.byteman.transform.all 12345
```

*The parameter 12345 in above command is the pid of your java process ID*

**Step 2:**

```
bmsubmit.sh -h 192.168.0.1 -p 8080 -l abc.btm
```

For more detailed usage of these command, please refer to the corresponding command help.

Furthermore, there is a programmer guide(PDF): http://downloads.jboss.org/byteman/2.1.3/ProgrammersGuide-2.1.3.1.pdf